# how to allow php_flag allow_url_include On

Tags: .htaccess

I can see in my info.php I created that allow_url_include is Off.

So I tried to enable it with .htaccess file with this line

```
php_flag allow_url_include On
```

After refreshing info.php it is still on Off.

Is there another way to enable this url include or was this the wrong line in .htaccess?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`allow_url_include` is a `PHP_INI_SYSTEM` directive and hence cannot be set with the mod_php5 `php_flag`.  If you are running GCI mode (as is the case with most shared hosting PHP configurations then yo can set this directive in your **php.ini**.

Note that doing this is not recommended as allowing URI-based inclusions this is a global setting which is in general both insecure and efficient and renders your scripts extremely vulnerable to attack.  If you do need to do this on an exceptional basis, it is better to read the script into  string and evaluate this.